# Populate select box when clicking link

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, drop-down-menu, populate

I have a tshirt page where the user needs to pick a color and a size (see [example here][1])

I need to populate the "sizes" dropdown when the user click a color (an image with a link).

The code of the color image/link that will be used to populate the  looks like this:

```
<a  onclick="document.getElementById('productColor10474717').value='120';" class="colorlink" href="https://www.example.com/tshirt_image.php?a=10474717&color=120" target="tshirt_image">
```

[image]

(in this link, the color code would be 120)

I already made a php script to get the results that must be populated in the dropdown:
https://example.com/_test/tshirt_ajax.php?checkshop=266497&checkproducttype=210&stockcolor=2

"&stockcolor" is the variable for the color code. The other 2 variables must stay untouched

The php page will return something like that:

```
[{"optionValue":2, "optionDisplay": "2"},{"optionValue":3, "optionDisplay": "3"},{"optionValue":4, "optionDisplay": "4"},{"optionValue":5, "optionDisplay": "5"},{"optionValue":6, "optionDisplay": "6"}]
```

I'm really newbie with AJAX and i have no idea how to implement the AJAX on the tshirt page to get the results from the php page using the color code variable and then populate it into the dropdown box, and i would need help to do it

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at the jquery-ui autocomplete widget - http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: But the dropdown box already looks populated to me

Comment: It is populated just to give an example. I need to populate it based on the results of the php script i linked, because the script will check the stock state of my t-shirts supplier and return only the sizes that are not out-of-stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the php file print results like

```
<option value="optionValue">optionResult</option>
<option>.......</option>
<option>.......</option>
```

add id="stockcolor" to each (a) element and remove the hyperlinks and onclick javascript like:

```
<a id="63" class="colorlink" href="#">
    <img src="https://image.spreadshirt.com/image-server/v1/appearances/63" width="24" height="24" class="cnormal">
</a>
```

install jquery (add this line to the head of your document):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then use ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Untitled-3.php?checkshop=266497&checkproducttype=210&stockcolor=" + $('#productColor10474717').val(),
        success: function(data){
            $('select#size').html(data);
    }
    });


    $('a.colorlink').click(function(){
    var stockcolor = $(this).attr('id'),
        checkshop = 266497,
        checkproducttype = 210;

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "tshirt_ajax.php?checkshop=" + checkshop + "&checkproducttype=" + checkproducttype + "&stockcolor=" + stockcolor,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#productColor10474717').val(stockcolor);
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('select#size').html(data);
            $('#tshirt_image').attr('src', 'https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/tshirt_image.php?a=10474717&color=' + stockcolor)
        }
    });

    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it's not working, not sure what i did wrong

new tshirt page with your ajax code:
https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/_test/tshirt_ajax1.php

new php results with <option> tags:
https://ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/_test/tshirt_ajax2.php?checkshop=266497&checkproducttype=210&stockcolor=2

btw, the "stockcolor" variable is different for each color and i have 11 color for each t-shirts so if i set the variable in the ajax script then all colors will use the same "stockcolor" ID which will be a problem. The "stockcolor" variable needs to be found in the color image/link

Comment: you need to install jquery first before anything else, then you need to wrap the code with $(document).ready. as for colors you can easily fix that by adding the color value as an id attribute to the <a> element. i modified the code, check it again and see if it works

Comment: I tried the updated version but it's still not working. I don't understand what's wrong :( Btw do i put the ajax in head or in body ? In my php results page do i need <select> tag or just the <option> tags ?
Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: there's (,) missing in the code before (success:), also the url in ajax should be the path to the php file related to the server's root folder so it sould be "tshirt_ajax.php" instead of "https://ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/_test/tshirt_ajax.php". the script is usually added in the head section but it works too in the body section. in php file the output doesn't need select tag just options. it should be working now as i already tested it on my server, let me know if u get any problems though. ps(change ajax type to post instead of get for faster results)

Comment: Awesome it's working perfectly now ! One last question: is possible to add a variable DefaultColor=2 so when the page loads it populates the <select> by quering the php page for &stockcolor=defaultcolor (2)

Comment: you can use the hidden input "color" to set the default colour value, then you can use $.post() in $(document).ready to populate select options using the color hidden input value, see the updated code.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working, the select is blank when the page loads (but it still works when i change the color) https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/_test/tshirt_ajax1.php .... and one last thing (i promise :P) how can i pass the value of the current selected size (in size <select>) to the php page in the URL ? Then i could edit the php script to set the default <option selected> to be the same size that the user has currently selected. So for example if an user selects XL size and then click a color, AJAX will populate the select but the XL size will still be selected. Thanks a lot again !

Comment: your site is using https protocol and it's restricting post requests. i updated the code again, see if it works now

Comment: Thanks it's working now ! Now i'd just need it to pass the current size to the URL of the php page. Something like tshirt_ajax2.php?checkshop=266497&checkproducttype=210&stockcolor=XXXX&currentsize=XXX (where currentsize would be the current value of "size" select). Just give me your paypal account i will send you some money for your time and because i asked so many questions !